# How to make a banner code in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

Example client put this on their website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/banner.php?bid=123&affid=88"></script>
```

In my `banner.php` how do I implement it?

I try to get the banner id & affid using `$_GET` but it's not working..

Let me know the clue how to display the banner on my client site using this way.

my banner.php

```
<?php
define('X', true);
include_once('includes/connection.php');

$banner_id = intval($_GET['bid']);
$aff_id = intval($_GET['affid']);

$select = 'SELECT images FROM affbanners WHERE id='.$banner_id;
$query  = $db->rq($select);
$display = $db->fetch($query);

?> 

 <a href="http://domain.com/aff?id=<?php echo $aff_id; ?>"><img src="http://domain.com/images/<?php echo $display['images']; ?>" height="250" width="250" /></a>
```

I dunno how to make it work actually.

Comment: i still don't even understand what your question is. Are you trying to include a javascript file (which is that php) and have it write a banner to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/banner.php?bid=123&affid=88"></script>
```

So the script at banner.php should send a javascript:
so enclose your output in `document.write method i.e.

```
document.write('<a href="http://domain.com/aff?id=<?php echo $aff_id; ?>"><img src="http://domain.com/images/<?php echo $display["image"]; ?>" height="250" width="250" /></a>');
```

and send and set the header in php like:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $display['image']; ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo $display['images']; ?>
```